# validate front side form with jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, if-statement

For my input form I have an ID place in the top. Now I added a php backend validation and now I want a validation before the form to be submitted.

I did this with jQuery. The only thing is that the ID field is not required. But when someone enters the ID the form becomes an update form and the user does not have to fill in the rest of the fields

How can i make an if statement (like php) with jquery if (id field) is entered then not require other fields?

```
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add/edit carModels</legend>
            <div class="info">
            <p class="text-primary"><span class="requiredField">*</span> Required for new inputs</p>
            <p class="text-primary"><span class="requiredEdit">*</span> Only required for edits</p>
            <p class="text-primary"><span class="requiredEdit">*</span> If you want to update items you only have to fill in the values you want to update</p>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nid" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Nid<span class="requiredEdit">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nid" name="nid">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Title<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min4">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="model" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Car Model<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="model" name="model">
                </div>
            </div>  

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="brand" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Car Brand<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                      <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="brandOption" id="mercedes" value="mercedes">
                        Mercedes
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                      <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="brandOption" id="toyota" value="toyota">
                        Toyota
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                      <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="brandOption" id="renault" value="renault">
                        Renault
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="carmodels">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="color" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Color<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="color" name="color">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="engine" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Engine<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="engine" name="engine">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fuel" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Fuel<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fuel" name="fuel">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fuel" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Date build<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <select name="day">
                        <option value="">Day</option>
                        <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
                            echo "<option value='" . ($i<10 ? "0" : "") . $i . "'>$i</option>"; 
                        } ?>
                    </select>
                    <select name="month">
                        <option value="">Month</option>
                        <option value="01">January</option>
                        <option value="02">February</option>
                        <option value="03">March</option>
                        <option value="04">April</option>
                        <option value="05">May</option>
                        <option value="06">June</option>
                        <option value="07">July</option>
                        <option value="08">August</option>
                        <option value="09">September</option>
                        <option value="10">October</option>
                        <option value="11">November</option>
                        <option value="12">December</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="year">
                        <option value="">Year</option>
                        <?php for($i = 1990; $i <= 2015; $i++) {
                            echo "<option value='" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</option>";
                        } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <?php

    if(isset($_GET['status'])) {
        if($_GET['status'] == 'updated') {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-info">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
          You have succesfully edited an item</a>.
        </div>';
        } elseif($_GET['status'] == 'new') {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-success">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
          You have succesfully added a new item named: ' . $_GET['name'] . '</a>.
        </div>';
        }

    }

    if(isset($_GET['error'])) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
          ' . $_GET['error'] . '</a>.
        </div>';
    }

    ?>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".close").click(function(){
            $(".alert").css("display", "none");
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<script> $.validate(); </script>
```

Comment: where is your code you have written?

Comment: Here is a sincere advice for you. Please create a fiddle which clearly shows your issue and your goal. Then it will be very easy for everyone to debug your code.

Comment: I now tried to do it like this: If (input field) #nid has less than 1 characters then activate the validation. Otherwhise don't.. This is my code but ti doesn't work in this if statement

 var value = $("#nid").val();
    if ( value.length = 0 ) {
     $.validate(); 
    }

Comment: Btw you can try it with `if(value == ""){//your validation code.}`.

Comment: <div class="form-group">
     <label for="nid" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Nid<span class="requiredEdit">*</span></label>
     <div class="col-lg-2">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nid" name="nid">
     </div>
    </div>

Comment: var value = $("#nid").val();
    if(value.length < 1) {
     $.validate(); 
    }

Comment: <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.47/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>

Comment: to be clear: I don't want this (nid) field to be validated. only the other fields WHEN nid has not been entered

Validation works fine for other fields but I don't know how to turn it off when NID has been filled in

Comment: read my last comment again. The only way to get it sorted out is to put your code somewhere in the running form so that one can see what is happening already and what you want it to do. Explaining it in comments in pieces is simply waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple demo for you. You can get help from this [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/codeavenues/b2tf4fvL/).

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
```